# Math talk with constraint on words (e.g. only use 6-letters words)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am trying to find a math talk on YouTube, which I had seen a while ago. The only thing I remember is that it was an entertaining talk (like a fun challenge) where the speaker had a specific constraint on the words he could use. If I remember corrected, he was only allowed to use 6-letters words. So for instance, he replace "Proof : ..." by "Solved : ...", or "Theorem" by "Result", etc.
Did anyone watch this video as well, by chance? I would be glad to find the reference... Thanks!

Comment: How did he replace "the" or other very common short words?

Comment: @coffeemath : he just removed those, IIRC. He just kept the essential on the slides.

Comment: (Maybe it was not exactly this constraint, it could have been something like all words have to start with 'A', or Monosyllabic (see proof 9 in Philip Ording's book) ... but I think the constraint was about the number of letters).

Comment: There are many forms of [constrained writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing), and many poems with mathematical structure of some kind.  You might be interested in [Oulipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulipo).

Comment: We can read [here](https://roubaud.edel.univ-poitiers.fr/index.php?id=335#tocto1n3) some math text without the letter 'e' (lipogram) in French by G. Perec:"Mais nul n’a jamais pu savoir la conclusion à quoi Galois comptait aboutir dans son manuscrit non fini. Cantor, Douady, Bourbaki, ont cru, par un, par dix biais (du corps parfait aux topos, du local ring aux Cstar, du K-functor qu’on doit à Shih aux □ s du grand Thom, n’oubliant ni distributions, ni involutions, ni convolutions, Schwartz ni Koszul ni Cartan ni Giorgiutti) saisir un vrai fil sûr pour franchir l’abrupt hiatus. Tout fut vain."